# using ViewPager when add to windowmanager ( activity destroy)

Tags: android, window-managers

I am using windowmanager to show view in lock screen. When broadcast called activity is destroyed( because i call finish after register ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcastReceiver).

Ok when addView to Screen with type_system_error. I have ViewPager inside this View. Then the problem is i dont have Activity that alive to call GetsupportFragmentMager()???

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(--GETSUPPORTFRAGMENTMANAGER--);
```

Do anyone know this problem?

Comment: don't use fragments then. Use a view pager with an adapter with just views.

Comment: hi, just start activity in top of all and remove lock screen.